# Logo showing on some page but not on product categories pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, headers

I am using a bought theme, and i have added my logo in my navigation/header in appearence and it works fine on all pages. But not on product categories. It is like it is using some kind of standard template from the theme?

Comment: Which theme is it that you're using? What happens if you open your site in an Incognito tab? ... Maybe it's some caching that does it. If not, then I would just go through all the settings of the theme, but I know that is a long hike. But all themes are different, how this is controlled and set.

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot of the two pages, if it's not a problem.

Comment: Its merchandiser, but when i look at the source text, there seems to be a bug. Because the mobile header contains the logo on product categories.

Comment: Please add a link to the theme (ideally edit your question and add it there). And if you could add information on the 'bug' you've discovered to your question as well. Then it has two upsides: 1) It could potentially help others who might encounter the same bug (perhaps other users of the Merchandiser-theme). 2) People can weigh in with potentially fixed or ways to bypass the bug. And please be as descriptive as possible. :-)